# Is possible to inject html into Knockout custom element?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm creating a knockout custom element and I want inject some html into it. Something like what we can do with polymer.

I want do something like:

```
ko.components.register('hello-world', {
    template: '<h1> Hello World!</h1>\
                  <!-- My injected html must be placed here -->\
               <h1> Bye Bye World! </h1>'
});
```

Then my html will be:

```
<hello-world>
   <div>
     I'm just an example text!
   </div>
</hello-world>
```

And, after ko.applyBindings(), will be rendered:

```
<h1> Hello World!</h1>
   <div>
      I'm just an example text!
   </div>
<h1> Bye Bye World! </h1>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template binding:

.html file:

```
<script type="text/html" id="inner-template">
   <div>
     I'm just an example text!
   </div>
</script>
```

component:

```
ko.components.register('hello-world', {
    template: '<h1> Hello World!</h1>\
               <!-- ko template: 'inner-template' -->\
               <!-- /ko -->\
               <h1> Bye Bye World! </h1>'
});
```

Or use another component for nested element.

#### Update 1

Calculated inner templates:

```
ko.components.register('hello-world', {
    veiwModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            return {
               getTemplateName: function() {
                   var templateName = "inner-template";
                   // Template name calculation logic here...
                   return templateName;
               }
            };
        }
    },
    template: '<h1> Hello World!</h1>\
               <!-- ko template: getTemplateName() -->\
               <!-- /ko -->\
               <h1> Bye Bye World! </h1>'
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But I'm still having one problem. If I create n custom elements of same type in my html, the inner-template will be the same to they all. There is a way around this situation?

Comment: Your component can implement let's say "templateName" property, that you can use in the binding: "<!-- ko template: templateName -->". You can check my update 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves all my problems (at least with knockout :D)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See the section on [Passing markup to components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-markup-into-components) in the documentation.

> By default, the DOM nodes inside  will be stripped out (without being bound to any viewmodel) and replaced by the component’s output. However, those DOM nodes aren’t lost: they are remembered, and are supplied to the component in two ways:
>
> As an array, `$componentTemplateNodes`, available to any binding
>   expression in the component’s template (i.e., as a binding context
>   property). Usually this is the most convenient way to use the supplied
>   markup. See the example below. As an array,
>   `componentInfo.templateNodes`, passed to its `createViewModel` function

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to give this link. Vote up for you.

Comment: Please include the gist of the linked content in the answer itself; a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/162730) has some downsides, mainly for future visitors.

Comment: The gist of the linked content is that the documentation provides instructions on passing markup to components. :) The link itself is just a convenience.

Comment: If you're only providing a link, the answer should in fact be a comment. - The gist of linked content is not *that* it provides instructions, but the instructions themselves. Posting the most relevant instructions inside the answer prevents it from being a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/162730) as well as preventing [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) from affecting it.